# android google game service - Server control

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, multiplayer

Im trying to create my card game android app, I used playgamesservices samples (https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples).
Now im success to create a room and start game with players, and each player recive and send data from all the others.

Im develop a multiplayer card game, And i have a question about the initial of the game. 
I want the server will be the "manger" of the game, handed out the cards and each operation of the players will upload to the server and then the players will get the updates from the server. Instead every operation will send to all the players, and each player needs to process and calculate.

I know its possible if i created my own server-client design, But its possible in google play services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [Real-time Multiplayer API](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer#sending_game_data) is what you're looking for:

> Your game can use the real-time multiplayer API in Google Play games services to connect multiple players together in a single game session and transfer data messages between connected players. Using the real-time multiplayer API can help to simplify your game development effort because the API handles the following tasks on your behalf:
>
> - Manages network connections to create and maintain a real-time multiplayer room (a virtual construct that enables network communication between multiple players in the same game session and lets players send data directly to one another).
> - Provides a player selection user interface (UI) to invite players to join a room, look for random players for auto-matching, or a combination of both.
> - Stores participant and room state information on the Google Play games services servers during the lifecycle of the real-time multiplayer game.
> - Sends room invitations and updates to players. Notifications appear on all devices on which the player is logged in (unless disabled).
>
> To learn how to implement real-time multiplayer games for your platform, see [Client implementations](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer#client_implementations).

The [Sending Game Data](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer#sending_game_data) part states (emphasis mine):

> **You can use the Google Play games services to broadcast data to participants in a room, or allow participants to exchange messages with each other.** Data messages can be sent using a reliable or unreliable messaging protocol provided by Google Play games services.

With that, I think depending on how you'll implement it, you could use Google Play Games to manage game data between the server and the players (and between the players themselves).